# How to fix "Profile import error" when importing an OpenVPN profile on OSX?

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, openvpn

I've setup a new OpenVPN account on the server.  Login through the web interface works.  OpenVPN client for OSX has been successfully downloaded and installed.  User profile has been downloaded to local file system as well

Importing the profile from local file results in an error message "Profile import error"

Importing profile from server, and login to the server, also do not work

I've uninstalled and re-installed OpenVPN client, it does not seem to be a file corruption issue as noted here:

https://siliconbeacher.com/openvpn-connect-profile-import-error/

How can I import the new OpenVPN profile?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is related to the SIP feature of OSX 10.11 and later:

http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

Following these instructions to disable SIP allows OpenVPN to work as normal